# Seeking advice. Comparing two sigmoideal curves

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sigmoid-curve

Probably a very stupid stat question, but I am a bit lost and unsure of what to do! I have conducted a study testing whether two types of stimuli are processed differently. I have presented the two types of stimuli under different orientation conditions (i.e., rotating the stimulus from 0 to 180 degrees in steps of 30º). I am measuring reaction times to detect a change in the stimuli. As can be seen in the graph, both stimuli seem to have a very similar processing as both sigmoideal curves look very similar. In other words, the effect of rotation on reaction times is quite similar in both types of stimuli. My question is how can I test this? In other words, how can I test whether both sigmoideal curves are the same? Any help would be much appreciated!.[image]

Comment: This looks like a standard $2\times n$ contingency table that would be tested with a chi-squared test, but in order to assess this we need to know what your *data* are.  It's not possible to conduct a rigorous hypothesis test to compare two sketches of curves!

Comment: @whuber thanks a lot for your reply. I have tried to provide more information about my data. Thanks again.

Comment: Are these actual reaction times or (possibly more appropriately) their logarithms?

Comment: They are actual reaction times. I hsould have said that I obtain exactly the same pattern with percentage of correct responses.

Comment: In pharmacology we regularly deal with sigmoidal dose-response curves. The standard analysis is of location (ED50, the halfway up location along the x-axis) and range (largest minus smallest, or end minus start). If your data were drug dose-response then I would consider whether to change the y-axis scale to either log or square root to eliminate the heteroscedasticity, but I would not need statistics to be able to say that there was no important difference.

Comment: We need two more pieces of information: (1) How many observations are summarized at each point? and (2) What do the error bars represent?